# Charger showing correct voltage but very small amps

Tags: charger

My electric shaver stopped charging. It comes with a 110 to 15V/150mA charger. Measuring the charger's output with ohmmeter, I'm getting 16 Volts but only 5 or 6 mA. My question is, am I right to conclude the charger is broken? In a broader sense, what are the signs of a broken charger (besides the obvious case of when there's no amps and no voltage). What explains the fact that there is 16 Volts but such small current?

Comment: The charger is fine - it's your shaver that's broken.

Comment: current is only pulled by load not pushed as voltage. So, depends on the load current in a circuit can vary. Your electric shaver is the culprit here not a charger. A charger is working fine.

Comment: @Dhans thanks! I'd accept this if it were posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested:
                 current is only pulled by load not pushed as voltage. So, depends on the load current in a circuit can vary. Your electric shaver is the culprit here not a charger. A charger is working fine.
       If you haven't yet satisfied, check with a different charger to your shaver or different shaver with your charger, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If charger, then defective parts that convert peak voltage into current. e.g. e-caps with low ESR.